# spliting dataset for training and evaluation in Bigquery ML

Tags: google-bigquery

Does the BigQuery ML automatically split the dataset for training and evaluation? Or do we have to get manually 80% datset for training, 10% for validation and 10% for evaluation with logistic Regression BigQuery ML? 
If both are affirmative, which of these would be better?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, BigQuery ML will automatically split data for it's validation processes. It would also be fairly common practice for you to manually split a holdout set to perform some additional validation on data that the model has never seen.

You can use the `DATA_SPLIT_METHOD` argument to tell BigQuery ML how you want to split the data. The default split is `AUTO_SPLIT` which is defined as follows:

> When there are fewer than 500 rows in the input data, all rows are
>   used as training data. When there are between 500 and 50,000 rows in
>   the input data, 20% of the data is used as evaluation data in a RANDOM
>   split. When there are more than 50,000 rows in the input data, only
>   10,000 of them are used as evaluation data in a RANDOM split.

For more information I would recommend reading over the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create).

Comment: Just to confirm, it will only auto split the data if we put in that specific argument (DATA_SPLIT_METHOD) right? What happens if you don't put the argument?

Comment: @fokusfocus The default value is 'AUTO_SPLIT'. See the docs here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create#data_split_method