# How to explicitly split data for training and evaluation with BigQuery ML?

Tags: google-bigquery

I understand there's already [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58913361/spliting-dataset-for-training-and-evaluation-in-bigquery-ml), but it's a bit old and it doesn't really answer the question.

I understand that we can use the parameter DATA_SPLIT_METHOD to separate dataset for training and evaluation. But I how do I make sure that they're both different data set?

So for example, I set DATA_SPLIT_METHOD to AUTO_SPLIT, and my data set is between 500 and 500k rows, so 20% of data will be used as evaluation. How do I make sure that the rest of 80% will be used for training when I run my evaluation (ML.EVALUATE?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is BigQuery does it for you.

The long answer would be that [DATA_SPLIT_METHOD](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create#data_split_method) is a parameter of [CREATE MODEL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create#create_model_syntax) which upon called will already create and train the model using the right percentage set at DATA_SPLIT_METHOD.

When you run ML.EVALUATE, you run it for the model which will have DATA_SPLIT_METHOD as a parameter. Therefore, it already knows which part of the data set has to evaluate and uses the already trained model.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question I would say.

As stated in the BQ's parameters of **CREATE MODEL** by using the **DATA_SPLIT_METHOD** (i.e. The method to split input data into training and evaluation sets.), that is done for you.

**But** in case you would still like to split your data, then here is a way for a random sampling method:

---

```
-- Create a new table that will include a new variable that splits the existing data into **training (80%)**, **evaluation (10%)**, and **prediction (10%)**

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project_name.table_name` AS

SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN split_field < 0.8 THEN 'training'
        WHEN split_field = 0.8 THEN 'evaluation'
        WHEN split_field > 0.8 THEN 'prediction'
    END AS churn_dataframe 

FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROUND(ABS(RAND()),1) AS split_field
    FROM `project_name.table_name`
)
```

**split_field** = A field that generates a random number for each row between 0 to 1 (it is assumed that the numbers that are generated, are uniformly distributed)

Hope this could help.